# Rails4: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL scope :find_paid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I want to find all orders where paid =1.

So, I wrote

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :find_paid, lambda { |paid| where (paid: 1)}
end
```

It gives error

> unexpected tLABEL scope :find_paid, lambda { |paid| where (paid: 1)} ^

What is wrong?

Comment: There should not be any space between where and (,also no |paid|. hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :find_paid, -> { where(paid: 1) }
end
```

You do not pass any arguments into lambda, so no need to use a variable (`|paid|`).

You would find passing an argument useful if, for example, you create a scope which returns something based on passed argument. Consider following example:

```
scope :paid?, ->(paid) { where(paid: paid) }
```

You would use this scope as follows:

```
Order.paid?(1) # would return paid orders
Order.paid?(0) # would return unpaid orders
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. I tried your ways too before I post this. However, I made a big mistake. There should not be space between where and ( .

Comment: wow, nice to hear - Thanks!! :) It is a present from the company, I worked for some time ago (the best company I worked for so far), and it's CEO is from Australia :)